# Lambda vs Proc in terms of memory and efficiency

Tags: ruby, lambda, proc

I understand that there are different situations in which Procs and lambdas should be used (lambda checks number of arguments, etc.), but do they take up different amounts of memory? If so, which one is more efficient?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several differences between Lambdas and Procs.

1. Lambdas have what are known as "diminutive returns". What that means is that a Lambda will return flow to the function that called it, while a Proc will return out of the function that called it.

   ```
    def proc_demo
      Proc.new { return "return value from Proc" }.call
      "return value from method"
    end

    def lambda_demo
      lambda { return "return value from lambda" }.call
      "return value from method"
    end

    proc_demo    #=> "return value from Proc"
    lambda_demo  #=> "return value from method"
   ```
2. Lambdas check the number of parameters passed into them, while Procs do not. For example:

   ```
    lambda { |a, b| [a, b] }.call(:foo)
    #=> #<ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)>

    Proc.new { |a, b| [a, b] }.call(:foo)
    #=> [:foo, nil]
   ```

Comment: So there is no actual difference in memory usage, just whether or not they run the full method?

Comment: as far as I know there is no difference in memory usage. I have posted a second bullet point re: their differences

Comment: I've tried to edit the answer but they keep rejecting it. `lambda_demo` returns `"return value from method"`and not `"return value from lambda"`

Answer (score 1):

The Ruby Language Specification does not prescribe any particular implementation strategy for procs and lambdas, therefore any implementation is free to choose any strategy it wants, ergo any implementation may (or may not) take up completely different amounts of memory. Actually, this isn't just true for lambdas and procs, but for *every* kind of object. The Ruby Language Specification *only* prescribes the *behavior* of the objects, it *does not* prescribe any particular implementation or representation.

However, since there is only *one* class to represent *both* lambdas and procs, it is very likely that they take up the exact same amount of memory, regardless of how they are implemented and represented.

Answer (score 0):

The differences between Proc and lambda are mostly behavior related, and are answered better by Abraham and is also found [here](http://rubymonk.com/learning/books/4-ruby-primer-ascent/chapters/18-blocks/lessons/64-blocks-procs-lambdas)

The old answer talked about how Block is faster than lambda as explained and shown at [Ruby Monk:Ascent](http://rubymonk.com/learning/books/4-ruby-primer-ascent/chapters/18-blocks/lessons/54-yield)

Comment: @MitulP91 I might be wrong here.. I am comparing blocks and lambdas, and procs are slightly different.. take a look at http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2006/04/18/understanding-ruby-blocks-procs-and-methods/

Comment: -1 This is wrong. *Everything* in Ruby is an object—[Procs included](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Proc.html#method-c-new). A lambda actually is a Proc in Ruby.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall yeah as I mentioned, I was talking about Blocks, you can take a look at my first link about how blocks break OOP. I was leaving this just for the link in the comment, let me see if i can fix it